# Making sort use all CPU CORES

Tags: sort

[image]

htop is showing that the "sort" command only uses 1 CPU CORE (on an RPM based Linux distro). How can I tell it to use all the available CPU CORES?

Comment: Are you sure that sorts multi-threadable?

Comment: @slm yes, it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--parallel`:

> --parallel=N
>                 change the number of sorts run concurrently to N

Comment: This was introduced in coreutils 8.6, with a lot of bugfixes in version 8.8. Older distros (e.g. RHEL6) don't have this.

Comment: @pdw I presume OP has a recent version "It's 2015, not the 90'!"

Comment: RHEL isn't from the 90's.. 8-)

Comment: @slm he only said RPM based distro, not RHEL ;)

Comment: coreutils 8.8 was released Christmas 2010, so that's closer to 2015 than the 90' :)

Comment: [RHEL 7 was officially released on 10 June 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#RHEL_7), so it's entirely possible the OP had RHEL 6

Answer (score 2):

If you know the **PID** of the process, you could set the number of CPU cores as discussed [here](http://xmodulo.com/run-program-process-specific-cpu-cores-linux.html).

- If you do not have `taskset`, you could install it as,

  ```
  sudo yum install util-linux
  ```
- For example, to assign a process to CPU core 0 and 4, do the
  following.

  ```
  taskset -cp 0,4 9030
  ```

  With **"-c"** option, you can specify a list of numeric CPU core IDs separated by commas, or even include ranges (e.g., 0,2,5,6-10).

You could also launch the program mentioning specific CPU cores. So all these details are present in the above referenced link.